# Can't Find Cloud DLP Scan results in stackdriver

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-dlp

I am running DLP scans on few BQ data sets. There are few built-in actions to choose after a scan's been performed; like Save to BQ, Publish to Pub/Sub, Publish to Stackdriver etc. I'm interested in `Publish to Stackdriver` and not really sure what do I need in order to see dlp scan results in stackdriver. Here is the list of GCP services I can see in Stackdriver logging; `App Engine, BigQuery, Cloud Pub/Sub, SQL, Storage, Snapshots, Disks, Firewalls, Cloud Load Balancers,Kubernetes Engine, VM Instances` (just in case this is helpful)
[image]

Am I missing any permissions or its something else? I tried figuring it out from cloud DLP documentation but it was not very helpful.
https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/analyzing-and-reporting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page of doc you want is

https://cloud.google.com/dlp/docs/monitoring

Stackdriver was recently renamed  to Cloud Monitoring (but the UI hasn't been updated yet ther on the DLP page.)

Comment: Thanks @Jordanna! Agree, DLP documentation needs an update.